# How to add some properties from one array to another in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to loop through and add properties from an array to another array:
Array1:

```
const users = [
   {
      "id":"112",
      "firstName":"a",
      "lastName":"b",
      "address":[
         {
            "apartment":"1",
            "street":"north"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"113",
      "firstName":"e",
      "lastName":"f",
      "address":[
         {
            "apartment":"2",
            "street":"north"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"114",
      "firstName":"i",
      "lastName":"j",
      "address":[
         {
            "apartment":"3",
            "street":"south"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"1151",
      "firstName":"o",
      "lastName":"p",
      "address":[
         {
            "apartment":"4",
            "street":"west"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So, I have an empty array `const usersInfo = []`
I want to add only `id` and `address` in `usersInfo` from `users` array

What I am trying to do below:

```
    const result = this.usersInfo.map(item => {
  users.forEach((element) => {
    item.id = element.id,
    item.address = element.address.map(r => {
      return {
        apartment: r.apartment,
        street: r.street
      };
    }),
  });

});
```

But this returns an Empty array as a result.

**I need output like below**

```
const usersInfo = [
    {
      id: '112',
      address:[{
        apartment:'1',
        street: 'north'
      }]
},
      {
      id: '113',
      address:[{
        apartment:'2',
        street: 'north'
     }]
    },
    {
      id: '114',
      address:[{
        apartment:'3',
        street: 'south'
      }]
    },
    {
      id: '1151',
      address:[{
        apartment:'4',
        street: 'west'
      }]
   }
]
```

Comment: I assume `address:[apartment:'1', street: 'north']` is supposed to be `{apartment:'1', street: 'north'}`? Please provide valid JSON in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below:

```
const usersInfo = users.map(user => ({id: user.id, address: user.address}))
```

Comment: this is the optimum way!

Comment: If this solves the problem. You can accept it as your answer